# Is that possible to use variables inside a variable in Jekyll _config.yml?

Tags: variables, yaml, jekyll

In my _config.yml I have these lines.

```
paginate_label: sayfa
paginate_path: "sayfa/:num"
```

And I want use a variable inside a variable like this.

```
paginate_label: sayfa
paginate_path: paginate_label + "/:num"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** use liquid variables in :

- config files
- files front matter
- data files
- static files